# BottomSheetDialog Fragment Shared Elements transitions implementation?

Tags: android, material-design, android-transitions, bottom-sheet, shared-element-transition

I have a `RecyclerView` in a fragment with an item list. So when I click an item, a `BottomSheetDialog` opens. There are some views common for both of the views. So I thought to add shared transitions to this. I search StackOverflow, but I didn't find anything about shared transitions in `bottomsheetdialog`.

So my question is that, Is it possible to add shared element transitions to a `BottomSheetDialog`. As this is a Fragment, there should be a way right? Does anyone have experience in this. ?

I am opening the `BottomSheetDialog` like this.

```
holder.cardAgenda.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                AgendaBottomSheet bottomSheetFragment = AgendaBottomSheet.newInstance();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("documentId", getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId());
                bundle.putString("name", model.getName());
                bundle.putString("description", model.getDescription());
                bundle.putString("date", dateFormat.format(timeStamp));
                bundle.putString("location", model.getLocation());
                bundle.putString("status", model.getStatus());
                bottomSheetFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                bottomSheetFragment.show(Objects.requireNonNull(getFragmentManager()), "Agenda Details");
            });
```

So is there a way to set shared transitions like the `addSharedElement()` method in fragments.

Comment: Has anyone come across a problem like this?

Comment: anyone???????????